# IntellIj Idea 2018.1 cannout download sources with maven 3.6

Tags: java, linux, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I am using ubuntu (16.04 xenial). Ubuntu repository contain old version of maven (3.3), but I need 3.6 I download maven 3.6 from offical site, add maven folder to PATH environment variable `(/home/<user>/programs-in-path/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin)`. Now from command line my maven works fine. 
Then in Intellij Idea maven settins I set maven home direcory point to my newly installed maven folder `(/home/<user>/programs-in-path/apache-maven-3.6.0).`
When I press download sources Idea says: Sources not found

PS when at Intellij Idea maven settings I use bundled maven 3, or maven 3.3 from ubuntu repository installed via apt-get. Idea works fine

IntellIj Idea log:

```
2019-02-13 14:37:34,601 [439840293]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.setLoggerFactory(Lorg/eclipse/aether/spi/log/LoggerFactory;)Lorg/ecli
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.setLoggerFactory(Lorg/eclipse/aether/spi/log/LoggerFactory;)Lorg/eclipse/aether/internal/impl/DefaultArtif
<------>at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
<------>at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenArtifactDownloader.download(MavenArtifactDownloader.java:221)
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenArtifactDownloader.download(MavenArtifactDownloader.java:100)
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenArtifactDownloader.download(MavenArtifactDownloader.java:68)
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.downloadSourcesAndJavadocs(MavenProjectsTree.java:1389)
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorArtifactsDownloadingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorArtifactsDownloadingTask.java:55)
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:132)
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$000(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:32)
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$2.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:107)
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.lambda$runInBackground$5(MavenUtil.java:446)
<------>at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
<------>at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
<------>at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
<------>at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
<------>at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
<------>at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.setLoggerFactory(Lorg/eclipse/aether/spi/log/LoggerFactory;)Lorg/eclipse/aether/internal/impl/DefaultArtifactResolver;
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.resolve(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:1223)
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.doResolve(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:1178)
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.doResolve(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:1172)
<------>at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.resolve(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:1041)
<------>at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
<------>at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
<------>at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
<------>at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
<------>at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
<------>at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
<------>at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
<------>at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
<------>at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
<------>at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
<------>at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
<------>at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
<------>at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
<------>at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
<------>... 3 more
2019-02-13 14:37:34,602 [439840294]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1  Build #IU-181.4203.550.
2019-02-13 14:37:34,602 [439840294]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release.
2019-02-13 14:37:34,602 [439840294]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM.
2019-02-13 14:37:34,602 [439840294]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2019-02-13 14:37:34,602 [439840294]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Linux.
2019-02-13 14:37:34,602 [439840294]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last Action: Maven.ShowSettings
```

Comment: Please update to the last version where issue has ben fixed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203028

Comment: @Andrey thanks. After update it work great

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug of Intellij Idea -  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203028

After updete to fresh a version of Idea all works fine!